# type mismatch error while performing division

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make the trading calculator where user add values in the boxes and then divide it by the total number of values he put for example: `50 + 60 + 70 / 3` so, I want the division text box to calculate the number of boxes are there and  chose the number for division so user don't have to add the division value it will be automated. I will attached the sample

```
Dim total As Double
Dim text_percen As Double


total = 0
If Len(Trading_calculator1.txt_currency1.Value) > 0 Then total = total + Trading_calculator1.txt_currency1.Value

If Len(Trading_calculator1.txt_currency2.Value) > 0 Then total = total + Trading_calculator1.txt_currency2.Value

If Len(Trading_calculator1.txt_currency3.Value) > 0 Then total = total + Trading_calculator1.txt_currency3.Value

If Len(Trading_calculator1.txt_currency4.Value) > 0 Then total = total + Trading_calculator1.txt_currency4.Value

If Len(Trading_calculator1.txt_currency5.Value) > 0 Then total = total + Trading_calculator1.txt_currency5.Value

If Len(Trading_calculator1.txt_currency6.Value) > 0 Then total = total + Trading_calculator1.txt_currency6.Value

If Len(Trading_calculator1.txt_currency7.Value) > 0 Then total = total + Trading_calculator1.txt_currency7.Value

If Len(Trading_calculator1.txt_currency8.Value) > 0 Then total = total + Trading_calculator1.txt_currency8.Value

If Len(Trading_calculator1.txt_currency9.Value) > 0 Then total = total + Trading_calculator1.txt_currency9.Value

If Len(Trading_calculator1.txt_currency10.Value) > 0 Then total = total + Trading_calculator1.txt_currency10.Value

If Len(Trading_calculator1.txt_currency11.Value) > 0 Then total = total + Trading_calculator1.txt_currency11.Value

If Len(Trading_calculator1.txt_currency12.Value) > 0 Then total = total + Trading_calculator1.txt_currency12.Value

If Len(Trading_calculator1.txt_currency13.Value) > 0 Then total = total + Trading_calculator1.txt_currency13.Value



If Trading_calculator1.txt_divide.Value <> "" Then total = total / Trading_calculator1.txt_divide.Value

Trading_calculator1.text_percen = total
```

i tried the above code but its giving me:

> type mismatch error.

can anyone help?

Comment: Maybe try (eg) `total = total + CDbl(Trading_calculator1.txt_currency1.Value)`   Or tell us exactly which line raises the error.

Comment: In place of all that repeated code you can refer to each textbox like `For n = 1 to 13: With Me.Controls("txt_currency" & n):...`  (assuming this is a userform you're working with)

Comment: its giving me error on here: If Trading_calculator1.txt_divide.Value <> "" Then total = total / Trading_calculator1.txt_divide.Value

Comment: You need to check whether `Trading_calculator1.txt_divide.Value` is numeric in addition to checking it's non-zero length.

Comment: how can i check that?

Comment: Use the IsNumeric function - IsNumeric(Trading_calculator1.txt_divide.Value)

Comment: i fixed it myself some how figured it out. thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without explicit type conversions, you're relying on implicit ones, but not all strings can be converted to a double.. best have a function that takes a string value, handles errors, and returns a valid double - for example:

```
Private Function ToDouble(ByVal Value As String) As Double
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    ToDouble = CDbl(Value)
CleanExit:
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print "Value '" & Value & "' could not be converted and will be treated as 0"
    ToDouble = 0
    Resume CleanExit
End Function
```

Now you can streamline your code quite much (even more so with [Tim's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70429417/type-mismatch-error-while-performing-division/70429534#comment124498279_70429417)):

```
total = total + ToDouble(Trading_calculator1.txt_currency1.Value)
...
```

Side note, if `Trading_calculator1` is a UserForm and that code lives in that form's code-behind module, you'll spare yourself future troubles by referring to the form as `Me` instead, like this:

```
total = total + ToDouble(Me.txt_currency1.Value)
...
```

Make sure the function is returning a non-zero value for the divisor, otherwise you'll be getting a *division by zero* error now.

Comment: I tried to convert it to double like you said using "CDBL" in VBA and when i use "Me" it say "wrong use of Me" apart from that its still giving me error here: 

If Trading_calculator1.txt_divide.Value <> "" Then total = total / Trading_calculator1.txt_divide.Value

Comment: You *must* validate/convert *each and every single one* of the string values you're reading from user input in textboxes (or any other kind of user input from anywhere else, actually) - never trust user inputs! As for the `Me` qualifier, I've prefaced it with *if `Trading_calculator1` is a UserForm and that code lives in that form's code-behind module* ;-) if your code is in a *standard module* (.bas), there is no `Me` because there is no *current instance* ...which makes them a great place to expose macro procedures and user-defined functions.

Comment: i think i fixed it, basically, i took that code out of the module and add it right under the main txt box where it will run only in that class in this case the division box and it worked but i changed a bit so rather then taking the values directly from the main code and expected the division answer. I took divide the value after it gave the results of sum
map: 5+5+5= results then results/ selected value